# fish: whitespace in alias

Tags: shell, alias, fish

I am trying to alias an executable in a directory with a space in it. For example:

```
alias myfile="/home/ben/test case/myfile"
```

Now, this is not expanded the way I want (it thinks `/home/ben/test` is the executable). In bash you can add extra quotes:

```
alias myfile="'/home/ben/test case/myfile'"
```

Sadly, in fish this does not work. What should I do instead?

Comment: fish's `alias` is only a naive function for familiarity that creates functions with this name (and through `eval`!), and it's not surprising to find it buggy. https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/blob/master/share/functions/alias.fish I think you'd better learn how to write fish functions, although that is neither friendly nor quite suitable for interactive fun.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[alias in fish](http://fishshell.com/docs/current/commands.html#alias) is just a wrapper for [function builtin](http://fishshell.com/docs/current/commands.html#function), it existed for backward compatible with POSIX shell. `alias` in `fish` didn't work as [POSIX alias](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/alias.html).

If you want the equivalent of POSIX `alias`, you must use [abbr](http://fishshell.com/docs/current/commands.html#abbr), which was added in [fish 2.2.0](http://fishshell.com/release_notes.html):

```
abbr -a myfile "'/home/ben/test case/myfile'"
```

or:

```
abbr -a myfile "/home/ben/test\ case/myfile"
```

Comment: It used to work better! Unfortunately there is a regression in 2.2.0.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is migrated from the comment area.

fish's `alias` is only a naive [function](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/blob/master/share/functions/alias.fish) for familiarity that creates functions with this name (and through `eval`), and it's not surprising to find it buggy. I think you'd better learn how to write fish functions.

For your example given, it is converted this line of `eval`:

```
function myfile --wraps /home/ben/test; /home/ben/test case/myfile $argv; end
```

Therefore using `alias myfile="'/home/ben/test case/myfile'"` won't help too, as it gives some stupid output like `--wraps 'home/ben/test; '/home/ben/test case/myfile'` (look at that lonely single quote!)

So write a function yourself, and you will find fish is such nonsense that is ruins the interactive fun and the friendliness:

```
function myfile --wraps '/home/ben/test case/myfile'; '/home/ben/test case/myfile' $argv; end
```

Note that I haven't really tested this, and it only works if I got the idea of the syntax right.

And actually I have got enough of the `f??????-id??tic-shell` in 40 minutes when I read through it's built-in functions the first time.

Answer (score 1):

You're unfortunately being bitten by a [bug in fish](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/2220), where aliases containing whitespace are broken.

In any case, it is reasonably easy to write up a replacement:

```
function myfile
    /home/ben/test\ case/myfile $argv;
end
funcsave myfile
```

That will define a new function (`myfile`), set the contents to run your target with all of the command line arguments (`$argv`) and then save the function so that it is automatically loaded (`funcsave`).

As noted in another answer, the [abbreviation command `abbr`](http://fishshell.com/docs/2.2/commands.html#abbr) is another option for defining aliases, although in your case I think a function (alias) is actually more useable.